# How can we use a pagination controller in many view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I'm developing a simple application using angularjs.

I need to us pagination in the view. But i don't know how to use a pagination in many view.

And also know how to pass the data to pagination controller from the view

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "Pagination" by http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.